# Extract size info from ros2 bag in shell script

Tags: size, ros2, bag, info

In ROS1, one can use 'rosbag info -y -k size bagName' to get the bag size information. How can I do it in ROS2 with Shell Script? Thank you in advance!

"ros2 bag info -h" does not have -y -k choices. I do not want to install ROS1 to my PC. I hope all the commands are limited in ROS2.

Answer (score 0):

ros2 bags are just folder so you can use "du -hs folder_name/" to see the amount of space it uses

Comment: Thank you for your message, Sux! It is very helpful to me!